# Apache Spark with kafka stream - Missing Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, kotlin, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I have trying to setup the Apache Spark with kafka and wrote simple program in local and its failing and not able figure out from debug.

build.gradle.kts

```
implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.0")
implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.spark:kotlin-spark-api-3.0.0_2.12:1.0.0-preview1")
compileOnly("org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:3.0.0")
implementation("org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.0.0")
```

Main function code is

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("Ship metrics").orCreate

        val shipmentDataFrame = spark
            .readStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
            .option("subscribe", "test")
            .option("includeHeaders", "true")
            .load()

      val query =  shipmentDataFrame.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

        query.writeStream()
            .format("console")
            .outputMode("append")
            .start()
            .awaitTermination()
```

and getting error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:666)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:194)
    at com.tgt.ff.axon.shipmetriics.stream.ShipmentStream.run(ShipmentStream.kt:23)
    at com.tgt.ff.axon.shipmetriics.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:12)
21/12/25 22:22:56 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Comment: Please, consider marking an answer as correct if it works for you to make community aware or add a comment to the answer if something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The Kotlin API for Spark by JetBrains (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-spark-api) has support for streaming since the 1.1.0 update.
There is also an example with a Kafka stream which might be of help to you: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-spark-api/blob/spark-3.2/examples/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/spark/examples/streaming/KotlinDirectKafkaWordCount.kt

It does use the [Spark DStream API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) instead of the [Spark Structured Streaming API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) you appear to be using.

You can, of course, also still use the structured streaming one, if you prefer that, but then it needs to be deployed like is described [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#deploying).